# looping through a dynamic list in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, dynamic

I am writing a stored procedure to read a list of int values that is dynamic (a parameter to the procedure). Once I read this list I need to do an insert to another table for each value in the list. I am not very good at sql. Can you please help me? 
This is what I have done so far.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FunctionInsert]
(
    @CONTEXTCODEID INTEGER,
    @MASTERCASEID INTEGER,
    @LETTERCODEIDS VARCHAR(50)
)
IF @LETTERCODEIDS  <> '0'
    BEGIN
    WITH cd AS
    (
        SELECT  1 AS first, CHARINDEX(',', @LETTERCODEIDS  , 1) AS next
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  next + 1, CHARINDEX(',', @LETTERCODEIDS  , next + 1)
        FROM    cd
        WHERE   next > 0
    ),
    lid AS
    (
        SELECT  CAST(SUBSTRING(@LETTERCODEIDS  , first, CASE next WHEN 0 THEN LEN(@LETTERCODEIDS  ) + 1 ELSE next END - first)AS INT) AS id
        FROM    cd
    )
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT id
        FROM    lid
    ) l
```

I am getting the list of values in id as 1,2,3 if i EXEC FunctionInsert (@LETTERCODEIDS  = '1,2,3')

Now I need to loop through these and do an insert into another table.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].CaseLetters
(
    ContextCodeID,
    MasterCaseID,
    LetterCodeID

)
VALUES
(
    @CONTEXTCODEID,
    @MASTERCASEID ,
    --My values from the list need to go here       
)
```

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Your RDBMS is a relevent piece of information that is missing from this question.

Comment: It is just one table [dbo].CaseLetters where the data need to be inserted. In this case , it should be inserted as 3 rows

Comment: The letters RDBMS stand for Relational DataBase Management System.  It is synonomous with database engine, database software, and type of database.  Examples are Oracle, Sql Server, and MySql.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.. I am using SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I find myself wanting to loop through a set of values in SQL I usually end up using a cursor.

Suppose your stored procedure is populating a table called #tmp_id

```
DECLARE @ID INT

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID FROM #tmp_id

OPEN my_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS == 0
BEGIN

    -- This is the body of the loop where your logic will go
    -- Every value in the set returned by SELECT ID FROM #tmp_id will
    -- Be bound to the variable @ID for one iteration of this loop

    FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @ID
END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor
```

Let me know if I can clarify anything.